# Issue with PyCharm and RubyMine, JRE folder?

Tags: java, python, ruby, pycharm, rubymine

The **PyCharm** and **RubyMine** IDE's comes with a folder named `JRE` in the root installation dir, the `JRE` folder increments the size of the installation around 150 MB, well, I supposse that this folder just contains exactlly the same **java runtime environment** that an official **JRE** installer downloaded from **Java.com** installs, so my question is:

If I've previouslly installed `JRE` from **Java** site I can delete forever the `JRE` folder from **PyCharm** and/or **RubyMine** installation directories to reduce the total size?

I've tried to delete the `JRE` folder from **PyCharm** and **RubyMine** root directories to test whether the IDE's really depends from that folder and seems that both IDE's works as normally with the `JRE` folder deleted, but I need to be sure that is safe or not to delete the `JRE` folder from Pychar/RubyMine directories if I currentlly have `JRE` installed.

Comment: Yes, IDE comes with its own version of JRE on Windows. You can safely delete it and/or configure IDE to use your system wide (or another custom) JRE -- just check your .bat/.sh/etc file and see what environment variables it uses when searching for JRE. By overriding one of them (IDE-specific one has priority) you can point to desired JRE installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IDE comes with it's own version of JRE on Windows.

You can easily configure your environment to use your system wide or any custom JRE (and then delete bundled one if so desired). Just check `.bat` file in `INSTALL_FOLDER\bin` folder and see what environment variables and in what order it uses when searching for JRE.

By overriding one of them (IDE-specific one has priority) you can point to a desired JRE installation.